# Is it best for Canadians to get an Egyptian visa in advance or at the Cairo airport?

Tags: visas, canadian-citizens, egypt, cai

I read that it's possible to get an Egyptian tourist visa on arrival at the Cairo airport.  Is that the recommended method for Canadians?  If so, how much will it cost?  Are any additional documents required besides the passport?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally it is not required to have Visa tourist in advance for USA, Canada and most of Europe.
But this is only for Tourist visa, any other visa (work, businesses, diplomatic, ...) should be arranged in advance. Also this is for normal passports, official or diplomatic passports need advance visa.

Tourist visa can be stamped in all main airports for:

- UK citizens: £15
- US citizens: US$15
- Australian citizens: A$45
- Canadian citizens: C$25
- other countries: $15

Lately there are talks in Egypt about needing arranged Visa for solo-travelers. Which means that people travel in tourist groups will not require arranged visa.

To be sure, I think it is better to give a call to [Egyptian embassy in Canada](http://www.mfa.gov.eg/english/embassies/Egyptian_Embassy_Ottawa/Pages/default.aspx).

Comment: Slightly off topic, I see that you are from Egypt.  Is it safe to travel at the moment?  I heard there's the election happening at the end of November, should I wait until after the election to book my tour to Egypt?

Comment: It is/was Yes all the time. Just avoid Tahrir square. Avoid election stations during the election day and this is just for Cairo. All other places (Luxor, Aswan, Sharm, Hurghada, Dahab, ...) are calm all the time. Check USA Egypt travel alert (no alert any more) http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/pa/pa_5443.html

Comment: @ThierryLam: Please ask this as an actual question - I will vote it up. @ Yousf: Please answer Thierry's question when he asks - I will vote it up (-: